# Everything comes null when I try to filter entries by category - Craftcms 3

Tags: categories, params, null

There's an issue when I filtering by categories but everything comes null, I was debugging code but all the entries has the same problem! But I don't know why does this happens? The entry comes well because I can show the text, title and so on, but I can´t get the categories. The filtering comes from params on the url.

For example

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(craft\elements\Category)#3085 (62) { ["groupId"]=> string(1) "6" ["newParentId"]=> NULL ["deletedWithGroup"]=> bool(false) ["_hasNewParent":"craft\elements\Category":private]=> NULL ["revisionCreatorId":protected]=> NULL ["revisionNotes":protected]=> NULL ["_initialized":"craft\base\Element":private]=> bool(true) ["_fieldsByHandle":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_fieldParamNamePrefix":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_normalizedFieldValues":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_allDirty":"craft\base\Element":private]=> bool(false) ["_dirtyAttributes":"craft\base\Element":private]=> array(0) { } ["_savedTitle":"craft\base\Element":private]=> string(4) "News" ["_dirtyFields":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_nextElement":"craft\base\Element":private]=> bool(false) ["_prevElement":"craft\base\Element":private]=> bool(false) ["_parent":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_prevSibling":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_nextSibling":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_eagerLoadedElements":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_eagerLoadedElementCounts":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_currentRevision":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_enabledForSite":"craft\base\Element":private]=> bool(true) ["_uiLabel":"craft\base\Element":private]=> NULL ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(1) { ["customFields"]=> object(craft\behaviors\CustomFieldBehavior)#3086 (140) { ["hasMethods"]=> bool(false) ["heroLogo"]=> NULL ["copy"]=> NULL ["cta"]=> NULL ["svg"]=> NULL ["heroIcon"]=> NULL ["heading"]=> NULL ["icon"]=> NULL ["heroBg"]=> NULL ["backgroundImage"]=> NULL ["blocks"]=> NULL ["social"]=> NULL ["network"]=> NULL ["externalLink"]=> NULL ["formId"]=> NULL ["image"]=> NULL ["video"]=> NULL ["heroProductDetail"]=> NULL ["heroUseCase"]=> NULL ["bullets"]=> NULL ["tabs"]=> NULL ["testimonials"]=> NULL ["quote"]=> NULL ["authorName"]=> NULL ["circles"]=> NULL ["cards"]=> NULL ["stars"]=> NULL ["logo"]=> NULL ["accreditations"]=> NULL ["badges"]=> NULL ["blogs"]=> NULL ["column"]=> NULL ["hubspotFormId"]=> NULL ["company"]=> NULL ["authorCompany"]=> NULL ["optimizedImage"]=> NULL ["seo"]=> NULL ["copyBg"]=> NULL ["newsAndBlogs"]=> NULL ["featuredPressRelease"]=> NULL ["featuredEntry"]=> NULL ["featured"]=> NULL ["categoryBg"]=> NULL ["heroSimple"]=> NULL ["resultsLayout"]=> NULL ["assetType"]=> NULL ["resourceCategories"]=> NULL ["product"]=> NULL ["newsUpdatesSubscription"]=> NULL ["privacyPolicy"]=> NULL ["blogCategories"]=> NULL ["threeColumn"]=> NULL ["fourColumn"]=> NULL ["tableMaker"]=> NULL ["resources"]=> NULL ["resourcesCta"]=> NULL ["featuredImage"]=> NULL ["newsPressCategories"]=> NULL
```

Comment: Could you please post your section/field setup and twig code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue about this problem.
I have in my code

```
{% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('category') %}
```

but I change getQueryParam with queryParams('category');

```
{% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.queryParams('category') %}
```

and the problem was solved